# TextView not updated text in a Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to update a text in a TextView inside the Adapter. The text is not displayed/ update visually even using notifyDataSetChanged(). Use other visual forms such as enable and disable components are working ok! On the issue of TextView correctly picked up the object and its value to add +1 and update the visual text, but does not change.

```
public class QuestionsAnswersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QA> implements Filterable {

private List<QA>filteredData = null;

private ArrayList<QA> arrayQA;
private ViewHolder holder;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private Activity activity;

public PerguntasRespostasAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<QA> arrayQA) {
    super(activity, 0);

    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.arrayQA = arrayQA;
    this.filteredData = arrayQA; 
    this.activity = activity;
}

/**
 * Stores the visual components for better performance.
 */
static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvLocal, tvQuestion, tvAnswer, tvNumLike, tvNumDisLike;
    private LinearLayout llContainerLikeDislike, llContainer, llLike, llDisLike;
}

/**
 * Return the size of {@code arrayQA}.
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

/**
 * Return {@link QA}.
 * @param position
 * @return {@link QA}
 */
public QA getItemQa(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

/**
 * Insert {@link QA} in the {@code arrayQA}.
 * @param qa: {@link QA}
 */
public void addNewQA(final QA qa) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            filteredData.add(qa);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Return the {@code id} of the {@link QA}.
 */
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position).getId();
}

/**
 * Return line of the {@link BaseAdapter}.
 */
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final QA qa = filteredData.get(position);

    ...

    holder.tvQuestion.setText(qa.getQuestion());
    holder.tvAnswer.setText(qa.getAnswer());

    holder.tvNumLike.setText(String.valueOf(qa.getUp_count()));
    holder.tvNumDisLike.setText(String.valueOf(qa.getDown_count()));

    return convertView;
}

public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter mFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            ...

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                final FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<QA>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    };

    return mFilter;
}

/**
 * {@link AsyncTask} for the send data like or dislike.
 */
public class UpDownVoteWsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>{

    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private int id, flagUPDown;
    private String flag;
    private boolean isError;
    private TextView tvNumUpdate;
    private LinearLayout llContainerDisable1, llContainerDisable2;

    private void closesProgress() {
        progress.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", activity.getString(R.string.loading_send), true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(params.length > 0) {

            if(flagUPDown == 0) {
                flag = "down";
            } else {
                flag = "up";
            }

            String url = params[0] + id + "/" + flag;
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);

            httpPut.setHeader(ConstantsLab.ACCEPT, ConstantsLab.APPLICATION_JSON);
            httpPut.setHeader(ConstantsLab.CONTENT_TYPE, ConstantsLab.APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
                if (response != null) {
                    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

                        UtilsLab.setIdUpDownVote(activity, String.valueOf(id));

                        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String numString = tvNumUpdate.getText().toString();

                                String newNumber = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(numString) + 1);

                                /***********************************************
                                *
                                *
                                * This is the part of update
                                *
                                *
                                ***********************************************/

                                tvNumUpdate.setText(newNumber);

                                llContainerDisable1.setEnabled(false);
                                llContainerDisable2.setEnabled(false);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });


                    } else {
                        showErrorDialog(activity
                                .getString(R.string.erro_ws));
                    }
                } else {
                    showErrorDialog(activity.getString(R.string.erro_ws));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showErrorDialog(activity.getString(R.string.erro_ws));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        closesProgress();
    }

    private void showErrorDialog(final String error) {
        isError = true;

       ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a newbie my fault. 
In the case had not updated the QA object with the new value(qa.setUp_count() or qa.setDown_count()), was only updating the TextView (visually) and, when using the notifyDataSetChanged(), the getView () was called again and as the QA object instance still had the old value, the error happened.